# Get order item collection from payment magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get itemCollection from Payment ?

I get getOrder() on null for the below code

```
$payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment(); 
$items = $payment->getOrder()->getItemsCollection();
```

Comment: Where you try to get order information?

Comment: When order is completed during the sales_order_payment_place_end event

Comment: can you please share full information in question or event details?

Answer (score 1):

you can get first order id after getting order id load product,

```
$orderid = $payment->getOrder()->getId()

$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();


 public function __construct(
        ..
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        ...
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        $order=$this->order->load($orderId);

        return $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
    }
```

Comment: Rakesh, could you please tell how to do the above in this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127636/sales-order-payment-place-end-event-misfire in my Vendor\Module\Model\Engine.php, cause im trying the above code during the sales_order_payment_place_end event

Comment: have you check your order id is getting or not? if order id is getting then  you can do above way

Comment: No im not getting, the moment i m trying to update a product in backend, i get Call to a member function getOrder() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_3\app\code\Vendor\Module\Model\Engine.php on line 158

Comment: Any update @Rakesh

Comment: no idea for that

Answer (score 1):

Try following way:

```
$payment = $observer->getPayment();
$order = $payment->getOrder();

$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    error_log($item->getProductId());
    error_log($item->getSku());
}
```